# LINQ to SQL *compiled* queries and when they execute

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following compiled query.

```
private static Func<Db, int, IQueryable<Item>> func =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((Db db, int id) => 
            from i in db.Items
            where i.ID == id
            select i
            );
```

This executes on the database immediately when I do

```
var db = new Db()
var query = func(db, 5);  // Query hits the database here
```

As in **before** doing

```
var result = query.SingleOrDefault(); // Happens in memory
```

But if this query wasn't compiled, as in

```
var query = from i in db.Items
            where i.ID == id
            select i
```

then it executes on the database **after** doing

```
   var result = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Note: This is a duplicate of *[When does a compiled query that returns an IQueryable execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445422/when-does-a-compiled-query-that-returns-an-iqueryable-execute)*, but all the answers on there seem to disagree with my findings.  I have posted my answer there, but I don't know how to get peoples' attention to it as it's over 2 years old.

Comment: You are right. Compiled queries are not composable, they return results when delegate is invoked not query itself. I have changed my answer to the referenced question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting question. Taking it to decompiled sources, when you compile a query, this is what happens:

```
public static Func<TArg0, TArg1, TResult> Compile<TArg0, TArg1, TResult>(Expression<Func<TArg0, TArg1, TResult>> query) where TArg0 : DataContext
{
  if (query == null)
    System.Data.Linq.Error.ArgumentNull("query");
  if (CompiledQuery.UseExpressionCompile((LambdaExpression) query))
    return query.Compile();
  else
    return new Func<TArg0, TArg1, TResult>(new CompiledQuery((LambdaExpression) query).Invoke<TArg0, TArg1, TResult>);
}
```

The UseExpressionCompile method is defined like this:

```
private static bool UseExpressionCompile(LambdaExpression query)
{
  return typeof (ITable).IsAssignableFrom(query.Body.Type);
}
```

This evaluates to false for the expression you've defined, so the else case is used.

The Invoke is like this:

```
private TResult Invoke<TArg0, TArg1, TResult>(TArg0 arg0, TArg1 arg1) where TArg0 : DataContext
{
  return (TResult) this.ExecuteQuery((DataContext) arg0, new object[2]
  {
    (object) arg0,
    (object) arg1
  });
}
```

The ExecuteQuery is like:

```
private object ExecuteQuery(DataContext context, object[] args)
{
  if (context == null)
    throw System.Data.Linq.Error.ArgumentNull("context");
  if (this.compiled == null)
  {
    lock (this)
    {
      if (this.compiled == null)
        this.compiled = context.Provider.Compile((Expression) this.query);
    }
  }
  return this.compiled.Execute(context.Provider, args).ReturnValue;
}
```

In this case our provider is the SqlProvider class, the SqlProvider.CompiledQuery is the class that implements ICompiledQuery. Execute on that class is implemented:

```
  public IExecuteResult Execute(IProvider provider, object[] arguments)
  {
    if (provider == null)
      throw System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Error.ArgumentNull("provider");
    SqlProvider sqlProvider = provider as SqlProvider;
    if (sqlProvider == null)
      throw System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Error.ArgumentTypeMismatch((object) "provider");
    if (!SqlProvider.CompiledQuery.AreEquivalentShapes(this.originalShape, sqlProvider.services.Context.LoadOptions))
      throw System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Error.CompiledQueryAgainstMultipleShapesNotSupported();
    else
      return sqlProvider.ExecuteAll(this.query, this.queryInfos, this.factory, arguments, this.subQueries);
  }
```

SqlProvider.ExecuteAll calls SqlProvider.Execute, which is a pretty big method, so I'll post the highlights:

```
private IExecuteResult Execute(Expression query, SqlProvider.QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, object[] parentArgs, object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, object lastResult)
{
  this.InitializeProviderMode();
  DbConnection dbConnection = this.conManager.UseConnection((IConnectionUser) this);
  try
  {
    DbCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = queryInfo.CommandText;
    command.Transaction = this.conManager.Transaction;
    command.CommandTimeout = this.commandTimeout;
    this.AssignParameters(command, queryInfo.Parameters, userArgs, lastResult);
    this.LogCommand(this.log, command);
    ++this.queryCount;
    switch (queryInfo.ResultShape)
    {
      case SqlProvider.ResultShape.Singleton:
        DbDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
...
      case SqlProvider.ResultShape.Sequence:
        DbDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();
...
      default:
        return (IExecuteResult) new SqlProvider.ExecuteResult(command, queryInfo.Parameters, (IObjectReaderSession) null, (object) command.ExecuteNonQuery(), true);
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    this.conManager.ReleaseConnection((IConnectionUser) this);
  }
}
```

In between acquiring and releasing the connection it exceutes sql commands. So I'd say you're right. Contrary to popular belief, compiled queries don't behave the same as uncompiled queries when it comes to deferred execution.

I'm pretty sure you can download the actual source code from MS, but I don't have it handy and Resharper 6 has an awesome go to decompiled function, so I just used that.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted to confirm that I wasn't doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have nothing to add to Andrew Barrett's answer except this:

- This is true (i.e. query hits database) when you invoke delegate returned by CompiledQuery.Compile() only for LINQ to SQL.
- If you use LINQ to Entities this is NOT true. Query doesn't hit database when you invoke delegate, it only does that when you start retrieveing data. Behavior consistent with non-compiled queries.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, that is right. It will not go and get anything until you ask it to.

Check out MSDN on [Deferred versus Immediate Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399393.aspx). In particular, you can [turn on/off lazy loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386920.aspx).

Look at the most upvoted answer on that question where the final List<T> is created. There is a select statement in there sending it off and asking for a result. LINQ will wait as long as possible to send of a request to the database.

By the way, you can investigate this easily if you set the `DataContext.Log` property:

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

Then you can watch the SQL statements on the console. By stepping through your program you can see exactly when the SQL statement hits the database.

Comment: Um, no thats not true.  It seems that for compiled queries it goes to the database as soon as the compiled query method is called.  This is what I am asking, I understand deferred loading, did you read my whole question?

Comment: I know how to look at it as I already said it is happening on the compiled query method call.  But I found it odd that the other question has everyone saying the queries execute on .ToList() when they clearly execute before ToList() at least for me.  So I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or whether it is the expected behaviour.