# Using a delegate CompiledQuery in a join?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a question related to [this previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167747/equivalence-between-regular-and-compiled-linq-to-sql). In an existing bit of LINQ which involves a number of **joins**, I'm trying to take each separate method comprising the join and convert it to a **CompiledQuery**.

First, the normal LINQ method:

```
private IQueryable<Widget> GetWidgetQuery()
{
    return db.Widgets.Where(u => (!u.SomeField.HasValue || !u.SomeField.Value));
}
```

And here, a delegate (field) definition for a CompiledQuery along these lines:

```
private static readonly Func<DBDataContext, IQueryable<Widget>> GetWidgetQuery = 
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DBDataContext db) => 
    db.Widgets.Where(u => (!u.SomeField.HasValue || !u.SomeField.Value)));
```

If I hover over the normal LINQ statement for the method **GetWidgetQuery()**, I see that it's a **method** as below:

```
(method) IQueryable<Widget> GetWidgetQuery()
```

However, the compiled query delegate (**field**) differs as follows:

```
(field) Func<DBDataContext, IQueryable<Widget>> GetWidgetQuery
```

Upon executing the latter as part of the LINQ statement, the syntax differs as follows. First, the normal LINQ's participation in the join:

```
var myquery =
    from wxr in GetWidgetXRQuery()
    join w in GetWidgetQuery() on wxr.WidgetID equals w.ID
    select new DTO.WidgetList
    {
        ...
    }
```

And here, the invocation of the CompiledQuery in the form of the delegate:

```
var myquery =
    from wxr in GetWidgetXRQuery()
    join w in GetWidgetQuery.Invoke(myContext) on wxr.WidgetID equals w.ID
    select new DTO.WidgetList
    {
        ...
    }
```

The former returns the expected result set; the latter, when I attempt **myquery.ToList()**, yields a **stackoverflow** exception, in part related to [this limitation of .NET 3.5](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/355026/stack-overflow-in-linq-to-sql), I think.

Can someone please help me understand how the compiled statement existing as a field (or I guess I should say a delegate) rather than a method is killing my query? In short I know what I'm doing is wrong, but I'm not sure I understand what I misunderstand.

Comment: Can you include the implementation of `GetWidgetXRQuery()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried doing roughly the same thing you're doing on EF 4, and everything seems to work fine. So it's either an EF 3.5 issue, or it has something to do with your implementation of `GetWidgetXRQuery`, or some combination of the two.

But the real point I'd like to make is that, as [Roy Goode stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167747/equivalence-between-regular-and-compiled-linq-to-sql/7168029#7168029) in an answer to your previous question, you lose all the advantages of a precompiled query once you extend that query in any way. By trying to perform a Join on your query, you are converting it to just a plain old query. So you might as well just use the non-compiled version which appears to work for you.

#### Update

Realized you were talking about LINQ to SQL. This sort of query does appear to have support in Entity Framework, but not LINQ to SQL. In .NET 4, I'm getting the following error:

> An IQueryable that returns a self-referencing Constant expression is not supported.

That doesn't mean much to me, but I'm guessing that it has something to do with the way the compiled query is represented internally. I still get the same error if I evaluate the query into a variable and use that variable in the query later, so it clearly has nothing to do with the difference between a delegate and a function. I still maintain that a compiled query is not appropriate to use here. Either you need to create one big compiled query to represent the whole query you want to perform, or you need to use regular queries if you want to piece them together this way.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: The actual monster that this simplified example represents is an IQueryable with conditional Where statements, I figured I'd start with what seemed like the simplest of the joined queries and compile it for performance, but as you suggest it looks like rewriting the entire mess as a CompiledQuery would be best. Also to answer your above question, GetWidgetXRQuery is just a normal query that grabs from a table with a single Where to filter by a flag column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this same error while doing db integration testing, and to jump straight to the point without trying to explain my specific issue.  Linq to Sql will create the sql query internally when using IQueryable and the moment you execute a method on that IQueryable, i.e. ToList() it executes that query on the database. So in my case I am joining to a method that returns IQueryable but is mocked to return a result, it is trying to compile that to a sql query but the IQueryable I created does not have an internal SQL query